# Wordpress : Pagination issue for page 5 and more for parent cat

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've got a weird issue on one of my websites.

I have a parent category. When I browse the posts from this parent category, I get a 404 from page 5 to the next ones. I call the URL www.site.ext/maincat/page/5 (or www.site.ext/?cat=XXX&paged=5 without url rewriting enabled).

When I browse subcats, I've got no issue. for example www.site.ext/maincat/subcat/page/5 works well. Even more, if there is no page 5, I've got a blank page (no posts) but not a 404.

I've set 6 posts per page. But If I set 2 or 100, I've got the error on page 5 (and more) everytime. No matter the posts displayed.

Page 4 and below are working well.

I declare the number of posts displayed just with : `query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=6');`

I've already set up the number of max posts displayed and rss feed to 1.
I'm using wp-pagenavi to display pagination but no matter if any plugins are activated or not, I've got this issue.

It's the first time I encounter such an issue. You can get it live there : https://www.dlmenuiserie.fr/nos-actus/page/4/ and https://www.dlmenuiserie.fr/nos-actus/page/5/

-- EDIT --

I changed my old query from that :

```
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=6');
```

to this :

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6, ); 
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now I have only 4 pages displayed. But I know there are other ones. So there is something with the query I think...

This issue is still only on the parent cat.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: are you writing the pagination code or is it a theme functionality?

Comment: I'm just using the standard pagination from the wordpress core. I use wp-pagenavi only to display the pagination menu.

Comment: please disable wp-pagenavi and check the issue again

Comment: already tested. and same issue.

Comment: switch back to one of the default themes twenty-four for example

Comment: That was a wise idea. With another theme, (tested with a few twentyXX ones) it works. The issue comes from the theme itselfs and not from the core... Something anoying.

Comment: I changed my old query from that :
`query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=6');`
to that :
`$args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        );
                        $query = new WP_Query($args);`

Now I have only 4 pages displayed. But I know there are other ones. So there is something with the query I think...

Comment: I suggest you contact your theme support and tell them about the issue

Comment: have you checked your theme options for blogging ? there might be an option for number of pages that you want to be displayed

Comment: Unfortunately, someone in my work (who is gone, it wouldn't be funny else) created this $*% theme from scratch (or almost... that might be the issue) and now I have to debug this code... so somewhere... I'm the theme support ^^ Thank you for your help. You helped me to go a bit further ^^

Comment: please write this code and give me feed back 
   echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The former dev who was working on this project did use a piece of code named bones. This useless thing had this in function.php :

```
function no_sub_cat($query) {                                 
if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) { 
    $cat_ID = $query->get_queried_object_id();            
    $query->set( 'category_name', null );                 
    $query->set( 'cat', null );                           
    $query->set( 'category__in', array($cat_ID) );        
    }                                                         
}
```

Just deleted this shitty piece of code and now guess what, no more issue !

Working from scratch... It's definitely the good way to follow !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if ( get_query_var('paged') )
{
    $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
}
else if ( get_query_var('page') )
{
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
}
else
{
    $paged = 1;
}

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6,'show_all'=>true , 'paged'=> $paged);
```

Comment: I don't see any difference. 
`var_dump ($args);` returns  `array(4) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(6) ["show_all"]=> bool(true) ["total"]=> float(4) }`

Comment: try this please
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6,'show_all'=>true, 'total' =>10); 
$query = new WP_Query($args);

Comment: if it displays 10 pages then we can solve this issue by adding some code

Comment: I've already tried this ^^ unfortunately it displays only 4 pages even with 99.

Comment: Still the same. $paged value is 4.

Comment: change it manually $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6,'show_all'=>true , 'paged'=> 10);